# Install and add local jar(gradle based) in maven

Tags: spring-boot, maven, gradle

I have made a jar of gradle based Spring boot project, where I have a class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Calculation {
    public int multiply(int a, int b)
    {
        return a*b;
    }
}
```

Then I made a jar

> external-0.0.1.jar

Then I try to install it in maven based spring boot project using:

> mvnw install:install-file -Dfile=F:\pull\external-0.0.1.jar -DgroupId=com.sakil -DartifactId=external -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=0.0.1

After that it was added in location:

> C:\Users\shahjalal.sakil.m2\repository\com\sakil\external\0.0.1

Then I add it pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sakil</groupId>
            <artifactId>external</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
   </dependency>
```

But when I try to import it :

```
import com.sakil.external.Calculation;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AcApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AcApplication.class, args);
        Calculation cal = new Calculation();

    }
```

Shows Error:
***package com.sakil.external does not exist***

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot will by default create an executable jar (for running it as a stand-alone application), which is not what you want when creating a library.

To have Spring Boot make a normal jar, add this to your Gradle project:

```java
jar {
    enabled = true
}

bootJar {
    enabled = false
}
```

May I also suggest that you use the [Maven publishing plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) to upload your library to your local repository? Otherwise, the pom file will not have transitive dependencies included.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct, when I tried your snippet in build.gradle , it worked fine. Previously my classes were in BOOT-INF folder, so when try to install that jar, it did not work.